# Why does the Mac OS X Finder append “ copy” to a filename when duplicating it but adds a number to it (2, 3, etc…) if it’s copied via drag and drop?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, user-interface

The title says it all. Not much of an issue as much as I am curious about some Mac OS X Finder behavior I just noticed today and if there is any documentation on this behavior.

In this first screenshot below, I simply duplicated the folder “Pics” via <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>—or via “Duplicate” by right clicking on the folder—the folder is copied with “ copy” appended to the name to make it “Pics copy”:

[image]

But if I selected that same “Pics” folder and the dragged and dropped it on the desktop, the new copy would be named “Pics 2”; and if I further copied “Pics 2” it would be incremented to “Pics 3” and so on:

[image]

But then… If I copied that “Pics copy” folder again <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>—or via “Duplicate” by right clicking on the folder—instead of getting “Pics copy copy” it is now incrementing so I now get “Pics copy 2”:

[image]

So, what is up with this?

- The first copy of a folder without the word “ copy” appended to it gets the word “ copy” appended to it.
- Copies made by drag and drop just get a number incremented next to the folder name.
- But any copies of the folder with  word “ copy” appended to it then get the number incremented.

Shouldn’t it just all be a number incrimination at this point? Or am I noticing an odd evolution in user experience on Mac OS X where someone at sometime just wanted “ copy” appended but then the incrementation issue was mixed in since how many “ copy copy copy” things can one filename endure?

Would like to know if there is any official Apple Finder documentation on this. Or perhaps someone whose history with Mac OS X goes back to the good old days could possibly explain this with some clear references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Finder appends "copy" to the name of a newly created duplicate of an object, the user can infer that the actual contents of the original and the duplicate are the same, at least initially.  When the Finder instead adds a number to the object name, it is intended only to disambiguate two otherwise identical names within the same container, and the user should *not* infer that the actual contents of the two objects are same (although they might be)...

BTW, this behavior goes back to at least System 7.5, as described on pg. 169 in "Macworld System 7.5 Bible, 3rd Edition" 1994, by Lon Poole, ISBN 1-56884-098-5.  I don't think finding an exact published reference from Apple is going to be easy. I looked thru my copies of Apple's "Inside Macintosh, Vols. 1-6", 1985, and "Macintosh Human Interface Guidelines", 1992, developer docs, but no luck.